# Laravel collection has not working as i expected?

Tags: php, laravel-9

I am trying to loop the array and find if a $value exists in it, I am using Laravel Collection for it. But I stumbled into an unexpected bug, am I doing something wrong?
I already rood the documentation but I haven't found any solution there. I think I am going old school here with a normal loop.
Collection is a good thing in Laravel, I hope that is my mistake.

Needle:

```
$value = "id";
```

Array to be looped:

```
 /**
 * Properties to be defined as private.
 *
 * @var array<string>
 */
protected array $privateData = [
    "id"
];
```

Not working :

```
/**
 * Return array with public elements
 * @return array $data
 */
public function toArray():array
{
    $data = [];
    foreach ($this->publicData as $value) 
    {
        if(!$this->includePrivateProperties)
        {
            if(!collect($this->privateData)->has($value)){
                $data[$value] = $this->get($value);
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Working:

```
 /**
 * Return array with public elements
 * @return array $data
 */
public function toArray():array
{
    $data = [];
    foreach ($this->publicData as $value) 
    {
        if(!$this->includePrivateProperties)
        {
            if(!in_array($value, $this->privateData))
            {
                $data[$value] = $this->get($value);
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Thank you for your help !
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: [has](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-has) checks for an existing key. You can use [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-filter) and [count](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-count), maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [contains](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-contains) to check if a value exists in collection.

Comment: has()
The has method determines if a given key exists in the collection:

contains()
The contains method determines whether the collection contains a given item. You may pass a closure to the contains method to determine if an element exists in the collection matching a given truth test

Thank you!